# What is the name for this type of phrase? 'seriously hilarious'

Tags: antonyms

When you use an antonym in a phrase: "this is seriously hilarious," what is this phrase called?

Comment: I would say it's "sadly humorous".

Answer (score 6):

**Oxymoron** — an apparent contradiction. A classic oxymoron is "Military Intelligence".

I first read "seriously" in the example as meaning "very", which could turn the sentence into an example of **sarcasm**, depending on context.

Comment: If you're going to cite "military intelligence," we may as well add "honest politician" and "objective journalist." :^)

Comment: "Jumbo shrimp" is even odder than "living dead".